# finding the hidden reference causing a memory leak

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Here's a pretty problem.   I recently had a memory leak in a java program where one huge object was not collected, even though it "should" have been collected when the whole complex graph of objects that contained it became
garbage.   (Concretely, the large object is an image, and the complex graph is a window and all the associated structures).

So, barring the unexpected (gc bug) there is some pointer somewhere leaking into the graph containing the image, preventing the whole mess from being collected.

How to find it?

Comment: Do you use [WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)-s? If you use that, improve your question. Maybe you forgot one!

Comment: Did you make a heap dump and analyze it? Even the most basic ones have a "Show path to GC root" function. (P.S. If you're using something like Java Swing, then quite a few objects have to be manually disposed to actually disappear, calling `setVisible(false)` and dereferencing is not nearly enough)

Comment: Valgrind? ......

Comment: I thought about implementing a "leak canary" using weak references, but the behavior of GC is very complex, and the fact something hasn't been collected yet doesn't mean it won't be.   In any case, finding what has been leaked is a different problem than how.

Comment: Grab the Eclipse Memory Analyzer http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ to make a heap dump and look for your object.